# Title for retiring founder continuing with the company in a consulting role

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

One of our founding owners is retiring and selling his share of the business, which is a Sub S Corp. We want to retain him on a consulting basis to mentor the younger employees, and to allow him to maintain his relationships with clients, many of whom see him as the face and voice of the company.

This term should be formal / professional and should connote his favorable ongoing standing with the company.

Is there a good term that would accurately describe his continuing affiliation with the company?

Searches for "founder", "emeritus", "founding principal", "consulting principal",and "consulting" have been looked at. Emeritus gives the wrong connotation in my opinion, because it implies he's no longer involved with the company. "Principal" implies ownership, which he won't have.

Comment: Founder director? Non-executive director?

Comment: This inquiry is based on opinions.

Comment: I would suggest that you could probably make anything up, as long as it not an official director's or officer's title. 'Senior Chairman', 'Senior Advisor', 'Advisor/Founder', 'Advisor-Founder', 'Retired Founder', 'Consulting Founder', 'Affiliated Founder', 'Senior Chief Founder Consulting Advisor Emeritus (Ret.)', 'Face and Voice'.

Comment: If it fits with their charter, this might be a better question for [workplace.se].

Answer (score 1):

Director [Emeritus](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/emeritus) might work for you.

> ADJECTIVE
>
> (of the former holder of an office, especially a university professor) having retired but allowed to retain their title as an honour.
>   ‘emeritus professor of microbiology’
>
> *[postpositive] ‘the National Gallery's director emeritus’*